# Admob issue when using GridLayoutManager with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview with `GridLayoutManager` and have its `spancount` as 3. I have two viewtypes - one for the recyclerview items and one for **`ads(admob)`**. Following is the result when my `spancount` is 3

[image]

You can see that the ad is not visible, now when i change the `spancount` to 1 it becomes visible like below

[image]

i think this is because the admob ads don't support these dimensions, is there a work around for this?

the ad is not showing up even if i try to hardcode the adsize
My question is that is there a way to fit the adview into my recyclerview with  `GridLayoutManager` and `spancount` as 3

Comment: Check log. AD need specific size(height&width) to load.

Comment: i have set the adsize as banner, then tried setting it programatically as well, but it is not supporting specific size, is there a work around? just wanted to show the ad as a recyclerview item

Comment: Probably the AD has not enough space to load. Are you using smart banners?

Comment: yes tried smart banners as well still dont fit. as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en-US), *The size of the container in which you place your ad must be at least as big as the banner. If your container has padding, that effectively decreases the size of your container. In the event that the container cannot fit the banner ad, the banner will not appear, and you will get this warning in the logs* , but is there a workaround, for example like a square banner?

Comment: @pRaNaY it says *Not enough space to show ad.* , does choosing a different adsize(like `BANNER`) would make it fit inside grid?

Comment: Yes, we can set dynamic span size when item is AD type. If item type is ad, it returns a span of 2 which set full width, otherwise it will return a span of 1 (half width). Check this:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/S9ke0zZRw10/udCPyNL8CgAJ

Comment: @pRaNaY worked! so helpful, thanks

Comment: Glad to know it helps you. Happy coding.

Comment: Please don't try to load the banner inside the RecyclerView it will against the Admob Policy.

Comment: Native ad is located for the RecyclerView to put between it.

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal sorry didn't notice your comment before, but native ads are not available from 2018 march 1 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. All you have to do is to call `setSpanSizeLookup` on your layout manager like below

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if (position % MainActivity.ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) {//your condition for showing ad
            return 3;//replace 3 with the number of items in each row
        }
        return 1;
    }
});
```

And then set the layout manager to your recyclerview.

Comment: Yes i have tried this way as commented by pranay, but is this aginst admob policy?

Comment: If you use it in a way that only one banner is shown on screen at one time, then it is not against admob policy. because the ad gets destroyed when you scroll the recyclerview.